# Get authenticated user profile using Twitterizer?

Tags: twitterizer

I'm trying to get the Oauth authenticated user's profile information using Twitterizer.

I believe this should be done using one of the TwitterUser.Show overloaded methods.
The problem I'm facing is that I don't have the username, just the Oauth tokens for that user.

Is there a way I can get the profile information using just the Oauth tokens?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TwitterAccount.VerifyCredentials(tokens)` will return the authenticated user.